# Examples of spatial generalized linear models

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, references, spatial

I've been reading some materials on Spatial data analysis, and I've a good background in GLMs. Right now I'm looking to find an example in spatial generalized linear models, but so far I've not found any. I'm aware of some packages in R such as GeoR. etc. but couldn't find a concrete example that includes codes, data, and analysis.

I was wondering if anyone can help. Please share links or papers.

Comment: The term "spatial model" is very broad. You could consider something to be a spatial model simply if you included the values of adjacent spatial locations in as a predictor (i.e. 'lagged predictors'). Can you be any more specific?

Comment: On the contrary, Macro, spatial GLMs are well known and clearly defined (albeit of fairly recent origin).  Actuary, have you seen the geoRGLM vignette at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoRglm/vignettes/geoRglmintro.pdf?  For a full reference see Diggle & Ribeiro Jr., *Model-based Geostatistics*, Springer 2007.

Comment: It also looks like chapters 8, 10 and 11 in Bivand's "Applied Spatial Data Analysis in R" book gives examples. The scope of that book is really amazing every time I go back to it, certainly worth having.

Comment: @AndyW I came to this thread to recommend that book!